# Laravel 5.6 $this->validate vs Validator::make()

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I saw there are a few other questions in which they asked what the difference was between `$this->validate` and `Validator::make()`. They didnt really answer the conceptual question I was wondering though.

Is there a proper use for each of these? Like when to use one versus the other?

How I am currently using it is in my API classes I use a if else with `$validator::make()` (like below) while in my Web portion of the program I use $`this->validate()` (also below)

Is this a proper way to use this?

**$validator::make:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required',
            'url' => 'required',
            'isPublic' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response($validator->messages(), 200);
        } else {

            Helpers::storeServer($request);

            return response()->json([
                'message'=> ['Server Stored']
            ]);
        }
    }
```

**$this->validate:**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'url' => 'required',
            'isPublic' => 'required'
        ]);

        Helpers::storeServer($request);

        return redirect('dashboard')->with('success', 'Server stored');
    }
```

Comment: And you have the [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation), which I like the most.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden wow, I haven't stumbled on this page. I will for sure read it over!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nope, they do the same exact thing two different ways. I mean that literally, `$this->validate()` calls the `make()` method on the validation class. If you look at ValidatesRequests.php, implemented by Controller.php which your controller extends.

The `validate()` method calls:

```
$validator = $this->getValidationFactory()
             ->make($request->all(), $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
```

So it ends up using the `make()` method eventually. There is a difference in how it is handled, since `$this->validate()` calls:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    $this->throwValidationException($request, $validator);
}
```

So using `Validator::make()` will allow you to handle the exception yourself, instead of `$this->validate()` auto throwing the validation exception for you. This is useful for doing something *before* your redirect. You show this in your first example, since you check if the validation fails before deciding how to handle it.
In the second example you know that if validation fails it will automatically refuse the request...

Comment: Thank you for the response, That's what I was thinking I was just wondering what the community thought. I just got into the laravel framework and even php in general a few months ago at my internship and I love it so I am trying to get into the roots of the framework and learn as much as possible!

Comment: Sounds good. I would try to go through some of the source files and learn from there. You can get a lot of info by looking through some of the base files like Controller.php, Model.php, etc. Some days when I'm bored at work I end up going through that rabbit hole and end up learning something useful.

Answer (score 1):

if fail any rules on `$this->validate`, will auto throw an error

`$validator::make:` you can easy handle the errors and may be you want wrap any data to array() and pass to `$validator::make:` for Validation

and also if you want to use FormRequest + Route Model Binding

your store() look like this

```
public function store(YourFormRequestRules $request)
    {
        Helpers::storeServer($request);

        return redirect('dashboard')->with('success', 'Server stored');
    }

public function update(YourFormRequestRules $request, Post $post)
{
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->save();
    return redirect()->route('example.index');
}
```

thats all

Comment: So The request would be "scanned" for errors before it is even passed to the controller?

Comment: the FormRequest allow you can reuse the rules, most is used on store/update, Route Model Binding if the id not found will throw 404, as you can see i didn't use find(id) on my update method

Comment: I will definitely look over the larvael docs for this and see how I can use it in the application! Thank you so much for the response!

Answer (score 1):

Using `$this->validate()`: `YourController` extends a `Controller` class which uses `ValidatesRequests` trait and it looks like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

The `ValidatesRequests` trait itself is made up of several methods that the base Controller gets and then your own controller and which includes:

```
validateWith($validator, Request $request = null)
...
validate(Request $request, array $rules, array $messages = [], array $customAttributes = [])
...
validateWithBag($errorBag, Request $request, array $rules, array $messages = [], array $customAttributes = [])
... and so on...
```

These methods helps makes some validation and request errors handling much convenient and in fact considering the mentioned `validate()` method.

When there's validation error in the request passed, it helps you handle the response without litering your controller with unneeded logic; i.e when it's an ajax call it returns a 422 response with a json body while it returns populates the error bag and fill the `$errors` variable for use in the blade template for non-ajax.

In summary, this only helps you incase you don't want to do manual validation by creating an instance of Validator, so to keep the developer focus on doing the real work ;)

**UPDATE:**

```
$validator = Validator::make() //creates an instance of the validator for further operations

// You can even do after the creating the instance of validator:
$this->validateWith($validator, $request)

//Lets do both steps above i.e the validation and trigger the Validation Exception if there's failure.
$this->validate($request, [...rules...], [...messages..])
```

> Check: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Answer (score 1):

Validator helper makes me more happy

```
$validator = validator()->make(request()->all(), [
    'type' => 'required|integer'
]);

if ($validator->fails())
{
    redirect()->back()->with('error', ['your message here']);
}
```

Laravel give helper that makes developing more convince.